# hover background image has gone

Tags: css

When I hover the `div` the `background-image` has been cover off by the `background:#444`, any idea how to show the background-image when hover ?

```css
body{
    background:#ccc;
  }
.mall_vjprofile_changebg{
 float:left;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:14px;
 background-image:url(../img/camera.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:5px 5px;
 padding:10px;
 text-indent:30px;
 margin:5px;
 cursor:pointer;
 border:1px solid #fff;
}
.mall_vjprofile_changebg:hover{
 background-image:url(../img/camera.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:5px 5px;
 border:1px solid #fff;
 background:#444; 
 color:#fff;
   
}
```

```html
<div id="mall_vjprofile_changebg" class="mall_vjprofile_changebg">Camera</div>
```

Comment: read the documentation properly because you are reassigning background property

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `background:#444;` from the hover state css.

edit:

If you need the background color too, try combining the background styles in one declaration:

```
background: #444 url(../img/camera.png) 5px 5px no-repeat;
```

Comment: but I need `background: #444`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `background: #444` from your hover state. If you want to keep the background color write your code like this:

```
.mall_vjprofile_changebg:hover{
    background-image:url(../img/camera.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:5px 5px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #444; 
    color:#fff;

}
```

Comment: but I need `background: #444`

Comment: Then add another wrapping div to have the background color

Comment: You can write the background as background: url(path/to/img) #444 no-repeat;

This will make the color the fall back

Comment: See modified answer to maintain your background color on the same div.

Answer (score 1):

> `background` can be used to set the values for one or more of: `background-clip`, `background-color`, `background-image`,`background-origin`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`, `background-size`, and `background-attachment` : [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background)

so you need to remove that `background:#444` in hover state and set

```
background-color:#444;
```

or like

```
 background: url("../image/camera.png") no-repeat  5px 5px #444;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The rest of us over-thought it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you set `background: #fff` it is overwritting the other shorthand properties.

You need:

```
background-color: #444;
```

You could also use:

```
background: #444 url(../img/camera.png) 5px 5px no-repeat;
```